# Not able to send email using SMTP through my .net MVC web application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, email, smtp, gmail

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add("my_id@gmail.com");
mail.From = new MailAddress("some_id@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "test";
string Body = "test";
mail.Body = Body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 495; //Also tried with 587
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("some_id@gmail.com", "passwordOfSome_id");
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

---

I am trying to run this code on my localhost. This code is written in my MVC3 web application hosted on IIS7. I am getting this SMTP exception -

`Failure sending mail (Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.194.66.109:587.`

I have tried swapping the from and to addresses also. Please help!

---

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try enabling support for "less secure apps" in your gmail account, because your code looks fine. Although I'd stick to port 587.

See here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Tried this but it didn't help! :(

Comment: I took the code, did this change in my gmail settings, and changed the port to 587 and it seemed to send me an email. I'm not sure what else to suggest.